# Cannot assign value of type 'BonusTableViewController.Bonuses' to type 'Bonus?' error in Swift4 and JSON

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I am trying to tap on a UITableView to get to a new detail view. My original code was based on a tutorial that created a data model to store the values in, which contains a class called Bonus.

In my main UITableView, I had the following for my `prepare(for: sender)`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        super.prepare(for: segue, sender: sender)
        switch (segue.identifier ?? "") {
        case "ShowDetail":
            guard let bonusDetailViewController = segue.destination as? BonusSubmissionViewController else {
                fatalError("Unexpected destination: \(segue.destination)")
            }
            guard let selectedBonusCell = sender as? BonusTableViewCell else {
                fatalError("Unexpected sender: \(sender!)")
            }
            guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedBonusCell) else {
                fatalError("The selected cell is not being displayed by the table")
            }

            let selectedBonus = bonuses[(indexPath.row)]
            bonusDetailViewController.bonus = selectedBonus
        case "ShowSettings":
            os_log("Going to settings.", log: OSLog.default, type: .debug)
        default:
            fatalError("Unexpected Segue Indentifier; \(segue.identifier!)")
        }
    }
```

The above code worked when I was manually loading the bonus data. Now that I am using a JSON file to populate the UITableView (and to get all the source data from), I changed the `let selectedBonus` to use my new `jBonuses[(indexPath.row)]` which is how my UITableView is now populated (using a JSON file). When I try to build this, I get an error stating:

> Cannot assign value of type 'BonusTableViewController.Bonuses' to type
>   'Bonus?'

on the code line that says `bonusDetailViewController.bonus = selectedBonus`

I don't think I need to change the Bonus.swift data model, since the labels and structs weren't changed, but I can't figure out what this error is trying to tell me to do, especially since my UITableView does load correctly and looks the same as it did before I was using the JSON based method.

I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the error message carefully and learn to understand it.

> Cannot assign value of type 'BonusTableViewController.Bonuses' to type 'Bonus?'

in the line `bonusDetailViewController.bonus = selectedBonus` means

- The type of the **left** side `bonusDetailViewController.bonus` is **`Bonus?`**
- The type of the **right** side `selectedBonus` is **`Bonuses`**.

so `bonusDetailViewController.bonus` has to be declared as `Bonuses?`. In your previous question you were using both types `bonus` and `bonuses`. Please consolidate your code to use only one them. Comment out the type you want to drop.

Comment: If I leave it as `let selectedBonus = bonuses[(indexPath.row)]`, it works. That should be directing to my original hand coded samples. When I change it to `let selectedBonus = jBonuses[(indexPath.row)]` (which is what the other question used as that indicates it is coming from the JSON file), that is when I get the error. I think my confusion is I don't understand why it works when it points to `bonuses` but not when it points at `jBonuses`.

Comment: You have to declare the type in the detail view controller to the same type as in master view controller. That's the issue. *Cannot assign ... to ...* indicates always a type mismatch.

Comment: This is going to take me a while. I'm just going to try to start this whole portion from scratch instead of trying to modify the old files as everything is too similarly named to make any sense of it and the old way had everything within the code itself, and I think that is causing conflicts galore with me trying to implement the JSON file.